# Grails WebFlow Error Handling

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, grails-2.0

Is there any easy way how to handle errors in the Grails Spring WebFlow in general? I mean not to have a try-catch block in each block but to have a general handler for the whole flow.

We found one solution to put some logic to error controller (accessed by mappings `"500"(controller: "serverErrors", action: "error500")`). But it's not sufficient way fur us because the exception is thrown anyway.

We'd like to catch [SnapshotNotFoundException](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/webflow/execution/repository/snapshot/SnapshotNotFoundException.html) which occurs when the user manually change the web flow step in url, let's say from `?execution=e4s2` to `?execution=e4s3`

Is there any way how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you add Global transition for Exception?

```
<global-transitions>
    <transition on-exception="java...SnapshotNotFoundException" to="..."/>
</global-transitions>
```

Comment: I see this answer has been accepted, but according to http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPWEBFLOW-57 the Grails plugin doesn't support global transitions. How can this work in Grails?

Comment: Interesting!!! I answered this question in general JAVA webflow context, don't have much idea about grails.